# Get PHP class property from array

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I have an array looking something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => my_val_one
    [1] => my_val_two
)
```

I then have an object looking something like this:

```
   stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 123123
        [name] => my_name
        [my_val_one] => stdClass Object
            (
                [my_val_two] => 1
                [my_val_three] => 2323
                [my_val_four] => 546567
            )
    )
```

I want to reference the following object value:

```
$ob->my_val_one->my_val-two
```

I'm not sure how to reference this class property from array values that I have.

Comment: can you explain a bit more, what you want to achieve?

Comment: How is the array related to the object (?). And why would you do `my_val_one->my_val-two` when these are two array values? That does not make any sense

Comment: Could you give us some background into why you need this, to begin with?

Comment: Considering your updated post, does `$ob->my_val_one->my_val-two` not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce) helps here:

```
$path = ['my_val_one', 'my_val_two'];

$value = array_reduce($path, function ($o, $p) { return $o->$p; }, $ob);
```

Comment: Spot on! That does exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know about array_reduce. I'll go off now and try to understand it!

Answer (score -1):

If I have understood correctly, you want to use the string values of the first array to access the StdClass object. You can do this by accessing the attributes dynamically. Here `$obj` is the StdClass and `$arr` is your array.

```
$obj->{$arr[0]}->{$arr[1]}
```